# How to make Cmake to include gl/GL.h?

Tags: c++, linux, opengl, cmake, debian

Hello I am new to Linux development, and just recently switched from Windows MSVS c++ development to Linux-based vim+cmake+gcc. I am using Debian Sid(unstable).

I am trying to get code on subdivision, I have gotten from a friend to run. I am not really used to Cmake, and googling for help often is troublesome, since every other dist seems to have different packages and different solutions.

> cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.6) 
> project (Benchmark)
>   Find_Package(Qt4 REQUIRED) 
>   Include(${QT_USE_FILE})
>
> find_package(OpenGL REQUIRED)
>   include_directories(${OPENGL_INCLUDE_DIR})
>
> set(CORELIBS ${QT_LIBRARY} ${OPENGL_LIBRARY} )
>
> File(GLOB SRC "*.cpp") 
>  
>   File(GLOB HEAD "*.h") 
>   add_executable(Benchmark ${SRC}) 
>   target_link_libraries(Benchmark ${CORELIBS})

That is my current Cmake, I want to use find_package(), GLOB etc to make it as dynamic as possible, and not use absolute paths.

I get the following error when trying to build.

> subdivbench/Matrix4x4.h:4:19: fatal error: gl/GL.h: No such file or directory  
> #include gl/GL.h
>   compilation terminated. make[2]: [CMakeFiles/Benchmark.dir/Matrix4x4.cpp.o] Error 1 make[1]: [CMakeFiles/Benchmark.dir/all] Error 2

The code is fairly irrelevant, since it's working perfectly in windows, all I need to do is to make the include etc work for Linux.

Comment: Are you sure you have gl/GL.h installed on your machine?

Comment: I have installed and included openGL, I have installed libmesagl1-devel, I have installed and included X11, installed and included Glut. If I didn't have gl/GL.h on the machine I would've gotten error from cmake, not during compiling. The fault lies in my cmake, but might as well be I lack the package on my machine, but that is too early to tell. gl/Gl.h should be inside all of the ones I mentioned.

Comment: This is strange. I have mesa installed on my system and made a small sample CMakeLists.txt:

FIND_PACKAGE(OpenGL REQUIRED)

MESSAGE("${OPENGL_INCLUDE_DIR}")


The output is:

/usr/include

-- Configuring done

-- Generating done

-- Build files have been written to: /home/phil/local/tmp/opengl

So your cmake code appears correct to me.

What I found out: I need to include GL/gl.h, not gl/GL.h.  edit: Sorry for that formatting, I did not know it does not work in comments.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Include GL/gl.h instead of gl/GL.h

Answer (score 1):

From what hanslovsky said:

> I have mesa installed on my system and made a small sample
>   CMakeLists.txt: FIND_PACKAGE(OpenGL REQUIRED)
>   MESSAGE("${OPENGL_INCLUDE_DIR}") The output is: /usr/include --
>   Configuring done -- Generating done -- Build files have been written
>   to: /home/phil/local/tmp/opengl So your cmake code appears correct to
>   me.
>
> What I found out:  I need to include **GL/gl.h, not gl/GL.h.** edit:
>   Sorry for that formatting, I did not know it does not work in
>   comments.

**This worked. Thanks a tons hanslovsky, it was just a capitalization problem.**

Comment: I added a post, so please mark it as the answer. I am glad I could help.